# Test if a doubly linked list forms a arithmetic progression

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

I'm working with my Linked List project. But when I try to solve the arithmetic-progression testing, I got this warning from Visual Studio 2015:

> Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation. q was nullptr.

And my code:

```
struct NODE
{
    int info;
    NODE *pNext;
    NODE *pPrev;
};
struct LIST
{
    NODE *pHead;
    NODE *pTail;
};

void Init(LIST &l)
{
    l.pHead = NULL;
    l.pTail = NULL;
}
NODE *getNode(int x)
{
    NODE *p = new NODE;
    if (p == NULL)
        return NULL;
    p->info = x;
    p->pNext = NULL;
    p->pPrev = NULL;
    return p;
}
void AddTail(LIST &l, NODE *p)
{
    if (l.pHead == NULL)
        l.pHead = l.pTail = p;
    else
    {
        p->pPrev = l.pTail;
        l.pTail->pNext = p;
        l.pTail= p;
    }
}
int isEmpty(LIST l)
    {
    if (l.pHead == NULL)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int testArithmetic(LIST &l)
{
    int flag = 0;
    int d = l.pHead->pNext->info - l.pHead->info;
    NODE *p = l.pHead;
    while( p != NULL)
    {
        NODE *q = p->pNext;
        if (q->info - p->info == d)
            flag = 1;
        p = p->pNext;
    }
    if (flag == 0)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Can you give me some advice to deal with this problem? Thank you.

Comment: This is almost a [mcve], but you've got some extraneous functions you're not actually calling, and you don't show the main function (or how your list ends up getting initialized/filled). Take a look at that link, and edit the code so that it is both minimal, and runnable.

Comment: Node q will be null when p is the tail of the list.

Comment: Isn't what you want to ask simply how to traverse a singly linked list?

Comment: @juanchopanza Possibly that's what OP _wants_ to ask. However, that's not what OP _should_ ask. The proper question is 'how to traverse _the whole list but last item_ to catch all _pairs_ of consecutive items'.

Answer (score 1):

```
while( p != NULL)
{
    NODE *q = p->pNext;
    if (q->info - p->info == d)
        flag = 1;
    p = p->pNext;
}
```

You test for `p` but then dereference `q = p->pNext` without testing whether it is NULL or not. You could try to check if the progression is arithmetic by remembering the last known visited value in the list (and starting from the second element).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an advice:
Based on a definition, to test if the values in the list form an arithmetic progression you need to verify if every *pair* of *consecutive* items make the same difference.

So you need to:

1. test if there is at least one such pair in the list, i.e. the list has at least two items;
2. calculate and store the difference between them;
3. and then traverse the rest of the list and test if each item makes the same difference with its successor (or predecessor, if you like), which you calculated in the first step.

Remember, however, to properly handle the tail of the list, in case you choose to test a successor – the last item in the list doesn't have one!